# Element positioning not working properly

Tags: css

So, I'm trying out some column code to get three columns lined up perfectly. Unfortunately, when I attempted it, I got the left and right columns floating over the middle column, like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3sqP.png

This is the css code I used. For reference, #left means the left column, #main the middle, and #right the right column.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>3-Column</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <link href="ThreeColumnProjectCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
 <div>
 <div class="column">
 <h1>Left</h1>
 <ul>
 <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
 <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
 <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
 <li>Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
 <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam</li>
 </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
 <h1>Header - Main</h1>
 <p>Ullamco laboris nisi sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. In reprehenderit in voluptate lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, velit esse cillum dolore. Sunt in culpa ut enim ad minim veniam, consectetur adipisicing elit. In reprehenderit in voluptate qui officia deserunt sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
 <p>Excepteur sint occaecat duis aute irure dolor sunt in culpa. Quis nostrud exercitation consectetur adipisicing elit. In reprehenderit in voluptate lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cupidatat non proident. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
 <p>Quis nostrud exercitation qui officia deserunt eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Consectetur adipisicing elit, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in reprehenderit in voluptate. Quis nostrud exercitation ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Velit esse cillum dolore qui officia deserunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
 <p>In reprehenderit in voluptate sunt in culpa. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ullamco laboris nisi velit esse cillum dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
 <p>Eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamco laboris nisi ut enim ad minim veniam, in reprehenderit in voluptate. Quis nostrud exercitation ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, velit esse cillum dolore.</p>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
 <h1>Right</h1>
 <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt excepteur sint occaecat duis aute irure dolor.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   border: 0px;
 }

 #left {
   position: absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:100px;
   width:200px;
   background:#fff;
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding: 0px 5px;
 }

 #right {
   position: absolute;
   right:0px;
   top:100px;
   width:200px;
   background:#fff;
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding: 0px 5px;
 }

 #header {
   background:#fff;
   /* IE 5.5 */
   height:81px;
   border-top:1px solid #000;
   border-right:1px solid #000;
   border-left:1px solid #000;
   voice-family: "\"}\"";
   voice-family: inherit;
   /* IE 6 */
   height: 99px;
 }
 html]body #banner {
   /* Mozilla and Safari */
   height: 99px;
 }

 #main {

   background:#fff;
   /* these two margins affect IE 5.5 */
   margin-left: 200px;
   margin-right:200px;
   border:1px solid #000;
   padding: 0px 5px;
   voice-family: "\"}\"";
   voice-family: inherit;
   /* these two margins affect IE 6 */
   margin-left: 200px;
   margin-right:200px;
 }
 html]body #main {
   /* these two margins affect Mozilla and Safari */
   margin-left: 212px;
   margin-right:212px;
 }
 #footer {
   width: 100%;
   height: 35px;
   border: solid #000000;
   border-width: 1px 0;
   margin: 0;
 }
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: please also post your html markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of the position absolute and use a grid system.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/C6CnJ/7/

```
.row { clear: both; }  

.column {
    width: 130px;
    margin: 0 10px 20px;
    float: left;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="column">Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="column">Lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, very good. Now, one last problem solving for this. In all columns, the words are pressed up against the border. I assume that increasing the size of the padding will produce space between the words and the border?

Comment: I updated it to add some spacing. You can adjust the margin in the column class.

Comment: I changed "margin" to "padding" cause that's the spacing I wanted, inside the box. But thank you for your help. You really did help me.